# The special use of that "have failed"

Tags: present-perfect

> If you sent out to climb a mountain, however you climb, you have failed if you cannot reach the top.

In this sentence, I wonder what does "have failed" mean
Please explain it specifically

Comment: I do not see the words `have done` in that sentence, only `have failed`.

Comment: Sorry,i mean have failed

Comment: Please tell us the source of the quote, and ideally give a link to the source

Comment: Also, do you mean "set out" or "sent out"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you set out to climb a mountain...

If you start climbing a mountain (which is a metaphor for doing any task)...

> ...however you climb...

...whatever route/path you take (or: however you go about performing the task)...

> you **have failed** if you cannot reach the top.

...all your effort is worthless if you do not attain your goal (or: complete the task).

"You have failed" is shorthand for "you will have failed" which is the [future perfect tense](https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/future-perfect-tense-use.html): it describes an action that, at some time in the future, *will have occurred* before that future time. If you cannot reach the top of the mountain, you *will have* failed to complete your task.

---

As an aside, I do not fully agree with the sentiment expressed in this sentence. After all, for many things in life, [the reward is in the journey](https://www.entrepreneur.com/article/240581) and [the real treasure was the friends we made along the way](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/maybe-the-real-treasure-was-the-friends-we-made-along-the-way).

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my confuse

Comment: I completely understand that.And i saw that in my textbook.